# Could not install B2B extension for magento 2.2.0-EE

Tags: magento2, php, composer, b2b

I have installed Magento-EE-2.2.0 with sample data. After installation, i tried to install B2B extension using composer

> composer require magento/extension-b2b

Used the following reference site

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html

Getting the following exception

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package magento/extension-b2b at any version for your
>   minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your
>   minimum-     stability

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.2.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento/module-bundle-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-customer-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-theme-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-widget-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-cms-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-review-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-tax-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-msrp-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-sales-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-gift-card-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-product-links-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-configurable-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-customer-balance-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-target-rule-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-multiple-wishlist-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-swatches-sample-data": "100.2.*",
        "magento/sample-data-media": "100.2.*",
        "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.0.1",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.0",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.1.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\ToolkitFramework\\": "dev/tools/performance-toolkit/framework/Magento/ToolkitFramework/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Anything I need to do on configuration before installing the extension.Please help to resolve it.

Comment: How did you install Magento-EE-2.2.0 with sample data? Also via composer? What does your composer.json look like?

Comment: I have added my composer.json file, I have installed Magento via browser GUI

Comment: is there anything I need to change on composer.json

Comment: @AnnaVölkl , my json is correct ?

Comment: Looks good. The only thing I am wondering (and don't know) is if this can maybe be an issue due to the sample data installed. I don't know if EE+sample data and then installing the B2B module will work at all.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl ok I'll try  WO sample data installation, is anything required to change in JSON file before trying to install the B2B extension? like  "stable" to "dev"

Comment: @AnnaVölklI have installed without sample data Magento2.2.0-EE then I tired but still i'm getting same error :(

Comment: I assume you have the right credentials added to your composer auth.json? Maybe check with the Magento Support if your credentials are correct to access the B2B module.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl yeah, I checked the file located at "/home/magesh/.config/composer/auth.json", it has the correct access keys. It will tell  "Invalid credentials" if my access keys are not valid.